# How can I access an enum member with an input in python

Tags: python, class, enums, attributeerror

I am trying to access the value of the `enum` variables with an input.

Here is my code:

```
class Animals(Enum):
    Dog = 1
    Cat = 2
    Cow = 3 

Choose = input('Choose an animal')

print(Animals.Choose.value)
```

Which gives me an error perhaps because `Animals` does not contain `Choose`.

How can I distinguish between a member in the `enum` and my input variable?

So that if I input `Dog` it would give `1` (the value of the `Dog` variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`getattr`](https://www.journaldev.com/16146/python-getattr):

```
from enum import Enum
class Animals(Enum):
    Dog = 1
    Cat = 2
    Cow = 3 


Choose = input('Choose an animal')

print(getattr(Animals, Choose).value)
```

Output:

```
1
```

`getattr` stands for "get attribute", which means it gets the variable in the class which it's name is what the second argument is.

`Enum`s have already builtin `__getitem__` methods, so you can directly index it with `[]` brackets, like this:

```
print(Animals[Choose].value)
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: @p-ekul your welcome :-) remember to upvote and accept if you find it useful :-)

Comment: @p-ekul Added another way for making it work

Comment: Using `getattr` like this is a poor suggestion, for example user can input any other attributes such as `"__module__"`, `"__class__"`, and even 'hidden' attributes such as `_generate_next_value_`. Custom methods defined on the enum are also valid attributes but not enum members, potentially causing more false positives. The correct answer is the one shown by Mark Tolonen using subscription, which was subsequently edited into this answer after he posted it.

Answer (score 2):

Enums have built-in access by string and various ways of accessing the result.  See the documentation for [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) for more details:

```
from enum import Enum

class Animal(Enum):
    Dog = 1
    Cat = 2
    Cow = 3 

choice = input('Choose an animal: ')

print(Animal[choice])
print(repr(Animal[choice]))
print(Animal[choice].value)
```

```
Choose an animal: Cat
Animal.Cat
<Animal.Cat: 2>
2
```